# Download links from page with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm already able to get all zip files link from a web page.

```
$Links = (((Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url).Links | Where-Object {$_.href -like “*zip*”} )
```

I get an error trying to download them:

```
Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $Links.HRef

Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Uri' required by parameter 'Uri'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:24
+ Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $Links.HRef
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I can only make it work with a single URL. How can I chain the HREFs with a Invoke-WebRequest in order to download all the URLs in my Link list?

Comment: `$links.href | foreach-object { invoke-webrequest -Uri $_ }`

Comment: It works, thanks! I'm new to PowerShell ... could you explain why a _foreach-object_ is necessary? Why can't I use something like:

    $Links.href | Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $_

Comment: Because invoke-webrequest doesn't support it. If you check the help `help iwr -online` or help for individual parameters `help iwr -parameter Uri` you can see "*Accept pipeline input? False*".  From looking around a bit, the `-Body` parameter accepts pipeline input, so it seems to be designed to call it repeatedly on the same Uri, I imagine maybe `Get-SomeData | Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://server/SubmitData.aspx` would post each chunk of data to the web service.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $Links.HRef` - you can see in the help `-Uri <Uri>` that means it accepts a single one. If it could accept an array of multiple Uris, the help would look like `-Uri <Uri[]>` - an array of uri types.  (Uri type can be automagically created from string input)